# Sending a TXT file via web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to have a web service which creates CSV data and writes it to a plain txt file on the client side. I was thinking of something like a GetData() method which returns a StringBuilder which contains the file content. The client of the service writes that into a file on the clients machine. Everything transfered needs to be secured, the web service runs together with a web app which is hosted on a https server...is calling the service secured then, too?

Would that work or are there any obstacles?

Thanks :)

Comment: to determine its chance of success: what is the client? who writes the client? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your client is under Java no ?

With SOAP protocol, you can generate a class which export all the method you want from your WSDL (server side) in your case GetData().

The client which is calling the WS doesn't have to be into a browser, so when you "receive" your datas (streaming) from the web server you can do what you want with them (writing them, ...)

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean...what about securing the stream?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot write to a local disk with a webservice, unless you have some kind of local-proxy (custom client) which does that job for you.